# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the HTTP protocol [HTTP/1.10x0aHost:]

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat9

Does anyone know how to solve these issues?  I see this in catalina.out logs at times when multiple users are logged in. I'm using tomcat9. I have seen few posts which said it'll be fixed in later versions after tomcat 8.5 but it doesn't seem so.

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the HTTP protocol [HTTP/1.10x0aHost:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:559)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:880)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1601)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
22-Apr-2021 19:29:41.943 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-16] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x000xdd0x010x000x000xd90x030x03U0x06p0x890xee0xadj1}0xe30x130xbd0xe60xda0xe50xbb]d0xf7\3ji0xb7T0xcbj0xb5Z0x840x07d0x000x00b0xc000xc0,0xc0/0xc0+0x000x9f0x000x9e0xc020xc0.0xc010xc0-0x000xa50x000xa10x000xa40x000xa00xc0(0xc0$0xc00x140xc00x0a0xc0*0xc0&0xc00x0f0xc00x050xc0'0xc0#0xc00x130xc00x090xc0)0xc0%0xc00x0e0xc00x040x00k0x00i0x00h0x0090x0070x0060x00g0x00?0x00>0x0030x0010x0000x000x9d0x000x9c0x00=0x0050x00<0x00/0x000xff0x010x000x00N0x000x0b0x000x040x030x000x010x020x000x0a0x000x0a0x000x080x000x170x000x190x000x180x000x160x000x0d0x00]. HTTP method names must be tokens
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:417)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:880)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1601)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

other times it had this in logs (again with multiple users logged in):

```java
May-2021 00:07:54.260 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-44] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [/?s=/Index/\think\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=md5&vars[1][]=__HelloThinkPHP]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:490)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
03-May-2021 02:28:48.523 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-63] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [/?a=fetch&content=<php>die(@md5(HelloThinkCMF))</php>]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:490)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
03-May-2021 21:19:01.628 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-14] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [/index.php?s=/Index/\think\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=md5&vars[1][]=HelloThinkPHP21]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:490)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

After this happens, the CPU Utilization went high and the EC2 instance was terminated. Does it actually increase the CPU utilization? I'm assuming these are two different issues. Could anyone confirm this?

I have seen few posts which said to add relaxed query characters in server.xml but is that the right way to do it? Doesn't it mean compromising on security?

What is the best way to solve this? Would adding the relaxedquery characters in xml be a good way to solve this since the Springboot http firewall security already blocks illegal characters like slash, semicolon, percent etc.

Answer (score 0):

The INFO messages you see are dues to various bugs in the **clients**:

- The format of an HTTP/1.1 request (described in [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3)) is a sequence of lines terminated by the characters `CR` (hex `0x0d`) **and** `LF` (hex `0x0a`). The client which issued the request only uses `LF`. Tomcat used to be more tolerant and accepted `LF` terminated lines: see the *"bug"* [65272](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65272),
- The second message reports an attempt to use TLS (the initial frame starts with the bytes `0x16` and `0x03`) on a plain HTTP connector. Probably it is caused by the same badly written port scanner that caused the previous message: since an HTTP request failed, it tried HTTPS,
- The remaining messages are caused by the lack of proper URL encoding of the URI path. Again, these are probably port scanners, which try to trigger a bug in some PHP software, just ignore them.

As a general rule you might ignore all these messages. If they bother you, you might put a reverse proxy like **NGINX** in front of Tomcat and use some [**fail2ban**](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) rules to blacklist the IPs that issue those requests.

Comment: great, thanks for the reply. So these messages doesn't cause the high CPU utilization? Could adding relaxedquerycharacters in server.xml solve this issue?

Comment: Those requests are stopped before they reach the web application, so they cause a minimal disruption. Adding some characters to `relaxedPathChars` and `relaxedQueryChars` will mean more work for Tomcat (although the messages will disappear): it will accept and process this fake request. Change you configuration only if **your** web application requires it.